# Q: ValueError Keras expected conv2d_14_input to have shape (3, 12, 1) but got array with shape (3, 12, 6500)?

Tags: keras, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray, conv-neural-network, numpy-slicing

I am building a CNN for **non image data** in **Keras 2.1.0** on Window 10.

My input feature is a 3x12 matrix of non negative number and my output is a binary multi-label vector with length 6x1

And I was running into this error **expected conv2d_14_input to have shape (3, 12, 1) but got array with shape (3, 12, 6500)**

Here is my code below

```
import tensorflow as tf
from scipy.io import loadmat
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Flatten


reshape_channel_train = loadmat('reshape_channel_train')
reshape_channel_test = loadmat('reshape_channel_test.mat')
reshape_label_train = loadmat('reshape_label_train')
reshape_label_test = loadmat('reshape_label_test')

X_train = reshape_channel_train['store_train']
X_test = reshape_channel_test['store_test']

X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train,axis = 0)
X_test  = np.expand_dims(X_test, axis = 0)

Y_train = reshape_label_train['label_train']
Y_test = reshape_label_test['label_test']

classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(3,3) , input_shape=(3, 12, 1), padding="same"))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
classifier.add(Activation('relu'))

classifier.add(Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(3,3), input_shape=(3, 12, 1), padding="same"))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
classifier.add(Activation('relu'))

classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(6, activation='sigmoid'))
classifier.compile(optimizer='nadam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size = 32, epochs=100,
                         validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), verbose=2)
```

After some searching, I have use the dimension expanding trick but it seem not to work

```
X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train,axis = 0)
X_test  = np.expand_dims(X_test, axis = 0)
```

The  X_train variable containing 6500 training instances is loaded from a Matlab .mat file with dimension 3x12x6500.

Where each training instance is a 3x12 matrix.

**Before** using the **expand_dim** tricks, the k-th training sample could be invoke by X_train[:,:,k] and X_train[:,:,k].shape would return (3,12). Also X_train.shape would return (3, 12, 6500)

**After** using the **expand_dim** tricks the command X_train[:,:,k].shape would return **(1, 3, 6500)**

Please help me with this !
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you manage your data wrongly. A `Conv2D` layer accepts data in this format `(n_sample, height, width, channels)` which in your case (for your X_train) became `(6500,3,12,1)`. you need to simply reconduct to this case

```
# create data as in your matlab data
n_class = 6
n_sample = 6500
X_train = np.random.uniform(0,1, (3,12,n_sample)) # (3,12,n_sample)
Y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(np.random.randint(0,n_class, n_sample)) # (n_sample, n_classes)

# reshape your data for conv2d
X_train = X_train.transpose(2,0,1) # (n_sample,3,12)
X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, -1) # (n_sample,3,12,1)

classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(3,3) , input_shape=(3, 12, 1), padding="same"))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
classifier.add(Activation('relu'))

classifier.add(Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same"))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
classifier.add(Activation('relu'))

classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(n_class, activation='softmax'))
classifier.compile(optimizer='nadam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size = 32, epochs=2, verbose=2)

# get predictions
pred = np.argmax(classifier.predict(X_train), 1)
```

I also use a `softmax` activation with `categorical_crossentropy` which is more suited for multiclass problem but you can also modify this. remember to applicate the same data manipulation also on your test data

Comment: Oh thank you very much, actually my problem is multi-label and not multi-class.

But does that mean that I should prepare my data set so that the form should be 
6500x3x12 (correct) instead of 3x12x6500 (wrong) ?

Comment: ok multi class or multi label doesn't matter (you can modify the network accordingly). yes, your data must be (6500x3x12x1)... remember to add also the last dimensionality with expand dims as I did in the code... don't forget to upvote and accept it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass data_format="channels_last" argument, bcoz your channels are at last

you try this:

```
x_train=x_train.reshape((6500,3,12,1))
x_test=x_test.reshape((-1,3,12,1))


and in each of conv2d layer conv2D(<other args>, data_format="channels_last")
```